# Colosseum: religious significance of setting sun and moon?

Tags: roman, goddesses

While studying the geography of ancient Rome, and particular the position of the Colosseum, I noticed on a [live webcam time-lapse replay](https://www.skylinewebcams.com/en/webcam/italia/lazio/roma/roma-colosseo/timelapse.html) of the Colosseum, that the full moon and sun settles over (or appearing to settle into) the Colosseum when viewed from the adjacent gladiator gymnasium.

I am aware of some of the deities of ancient Rome, such as Luna and Sol, and the significance of both deities in Mithraic tauroctony. Also, that [Varro lists Luna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_(goddess)#Cult_and_temples) as one deity vital for agriculture.

This lead me to wonder if the Colosseum was conceived as a public temple or place of worship, whereby attendees would participate in a sort of collective act of ritual sacrifice such as [illustrated in the relief](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bas_relief_from_Arch_of_Marcus_Aurelius_showing_sacrifice.jpg) of Marcus Aurelius depicted sacrificing a bull in front of the Temple of Jupiter... to ensure good crops and harvest, or appeasement, for example.

I am seeking to confirm my hypothesis that the Colosseum is in fact a place of worship based on my observation of how the building appears to interact with the sun and moon, and in light of related deities and ancient Roman cults in general.

I haven't been able to find any specific (academic, contemporary) information relating to the religious significance of the Colosseum as it pertains to the position of the sun and moon (e.g. in the same way the Giza Pyramids relate to the position of the constellation Orion).

**My question:** in general, is there any information about the religious significance of the Colosseum as it relates, in this case, to the worship of Luna and Sol?

I believe it is reasonable to suggest that the position of the Colosseum in relation to the motion of the sun and moon (symbolically) could relate to the Roman Mithraic Mysteries, which might explain the position of the Colosseum (East/West).

Note: perhaps in the same way Hadrian's Wall might have been designed to symbolise the Roman Empires universality.

**Edit:** '*in the Middle Ages, the Colosseum was thought to be a Roman temple to the sun because of the presence of statue of Nero-turned-Helios that stood next to it*'.

Other reference related to the connection between the statue and the amphitheatre: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_of_Nero.